# Getting a complete list of all column names from Azure Table storage programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-table-storage, nosql

I'm writing a web portal to interface with Azure.

I want to pull out and display the contents of an Azure Table store (nosql)

I am using :

```
CloudTable table = TableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);
IEnumerable<DynamicTableEntity> results = table.ExecuteQuery(new TableQuery());
```

This fetches the table and the entities.

[image]

Each returned DynamicTableEntity only lists the properties that have values.
Not having a list of all of the table properties makes displaying the data on a view troublesome.

Is there a way of getting all of the column names for the table programmatically using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.

Comment: Late, but you could exploit the nature of a schema-less database: add a row, PartitionKey Metadata and RowKey Schema_entityName - store a sample value of every column that an entityName could have. I know this isn't ideal, especially if you're interfacing with third party databases (creating some kind of management service), which you have no idea regarding schema - but it might help someone. Of course, you could also crawl the database and index columns for this schema and then add it (or request that users add a schema row manually).

Answer (score 2):

In Azure Storage, tables store data as collections of entities. An entity has a primary key and a set of properties. However, the Table service does not enforce any schema for tables, so two entities in the same table may have different sets of properties.

So, if the client application does not enforce a schema, there is no easy way to query the union of all properties of all entities in a table.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ended up just pulling out the data I wanted to display and doing a distinct on the union. Not the most efficient way, but it's a quick fix.

Answer (score 1):

I have made below custom logic and it is working perfectly fine for me

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> properties = new List<string>();
            var acc = new CloudStorageAccount(
                         new StorageCredentials("YOUR STORAGE ACCOUNT NAME", "YOUR STORAGE ACCOUNT CONNECTION STRING"), true);
            var tableClient = acc.CreateCloudTableClient();
            CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("YOUR TABLE NAME");
            IEnumerable<DynamicTableEntity> results = table.ExecuteQuery(new TableQuery());
            foreach (var item in results)     
            {
                if(item.Properties != null && item.Properties.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach(var property in item.Properties)
                    {
                        if(properties != null && properties.Count > 0)
                        {
                            string s1 = property.Key.ToString();
                            if(!properties.Contains(s1))
                            {
                                properties.Add(s1);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            string s2 = property.Key.ToString();
                            properties.Add(s2);
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }
            if(properties != null && properties.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach(var item in properties)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
                }    
            }
```

partition key,row key and timestamp are common properties for all tables you can add by default while creating list